# Alerts on Google Dataflow Aggregator

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is there a way to set an alerts on `com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.Aggregator`? We can view current counter on Dataflow UI but there is no way to get current value from the aggregator instance or read current value from the stackdrive.

Comment: Not at the moment, but we are working on better integrating Dataflow with Stackdriver, and future enhancements to alerting in Dataflow will be made via Stackdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment, but we are working on better integrating Dataflow with Stackdriver, and future enhancements to alerting in Dataflow will be made via Stackdriver